# How do I merge two SELECT queries with different WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, union-all

I'm trying to write query on two different selects with different WHERE clause and using GROUP BY.
I browsed for examples but mine is different since I have multiple fields for SELECT.
Here is example data:

```
--    drop table #temp_counts;
create table #temp_counts(
report_date smalldatetime not null, 
Emp_id varchar(10) not null,
source_system varchar(10) not null
)

Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-02 00:00:00', '12411', 'ABC');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-02 00:00:00', '56421', 'ABC');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-02 00:00:00', '45411', 'ABC');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-02 00:00:00', '75411', 'ABC');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-02 00:00:00', '13245', 'XYZ');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-02 00:00:00', '66245', 'XYZ');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-02 00:00:00', '77245', 'XYZ');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-02 00:00:00', '98245', 'XYZ');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-02 00:00:00', '34245', 'XYZ');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-02 00:00:00', '29245', 'XYZ');

Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-03 00:00:00', '14524', 'ABC');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-03 00:00:00', '17824', 'ABC');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-03 00:00:00', '32524', 'ABC');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-03 00:00:00', '16724', 'XYZ');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-03 00:00:00', '19924', 'XYZ');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-03 00:00:00', '89424', 'XYZ');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-03 00:00:00', '48324', 'XYZ');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-03 00:00:00', '16000', 'XYZ');

Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-04 00:00:00', '18724', 'ABC');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-04 00:00:00', '12904', 'XYZ');

Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-05 00:00:00', '12074', 'ABC');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-05 00:00:00', '12784', 'XYZ');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-05 00:00:00', '12324', 'XYZ');
Insert into #temp_counts values ('2021-05-05 00:00:00', '75124', 'XYZ');
```

These are the queries I would like to merge:

```
select count(*) emp_count,  report_date , 'ABC' source_system from #temp_counts 
where  source_system = 'ABC'
group by report_date
order by report_date

select count(*) emp_count,  report_date , 'XYZ' source_system from #temp_counts 
where  source_system = 'XYZ'
group by report_date
order by report_date
```

I tried 2 methods as under:

```
--Method 1
select fir.emp_count, fir.report_date, fir.source_system from
(select count(*) emp_count,  report_date , 'ABC' source_system from #temp_counts 
where  source_system = 'ABC') as fir
inner join
(select count(*) emp_count,  report_date , 'XYZ' source_system from #temp_counts 
where  source_system = 'XYZ') as sec
on fir.report_date = sec.report_date
group by fir.report_date
order by fir.report_date
--Method 2
select count(*) emp_count,  report_date , 'ABC' source_system from #temp_counts 
where  source_system = 'ABC'
UNION ALL
select count(*) emp_count,  report_date , 'XYZ' source_system from #temp_counts 
where  source_system = 'XYZ'
group by report_date
order by report_date
```

Both give Error:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 61
Column '#temp_counts.report_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Please guide

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems like you just want to group by report_date and source_system:

```
select count(*) emp_count,  report_date , source_system 
FROM #temp_counts
group by report_date, source_system
order by source_system,report_date
```

if you want to have result for specific source systems then you can combine conditions:

```
select count(*) emp_count,  report_date , source_system 
FROM #temp_counts 
where  source_system in ('ABC', 'XYZ')
group by report_date, source_system
order by source_system,report_date
```

you can change order by to show rows in the order you want to show

just to illustrate how to use union :

```
select count(*) emp_count,  report_date , source_system from #temp_counts 
where  source_system = 'ABC'
group by report_date

union all

select count(*) emp_count,  report_date , source_system from #temp_counts 
where  source_system = 'XYZ'
group by report_date
order by source_system, report_date
```

Comment: I would still like to know solution using UNION or UNION ALL